# How to find stream type in java-8

Tags: java, java-8

I have method with `Stream` object as argument, in that method i have to perform some actions based on `Stream` type. But `instanceof` is not working and gives me compile error

```
public <T>boolean objectIsNullOREmpty(Stream<T> str) {
    if(str instanceof Stream<String>) {
        //do some actions
    }

    if(Str instanceof Stream<SomeClass>) {
        //do some actions
    }
}
```

**Compile Error**

> Cannot perform instanceof check against parameterized type Stream. Use the form Stream instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a problem of streams.  The error reflects the way that generic types were implemented in Java.

Java generic types are **non-reifiable**.

In Java, generic types have less type information available at run time than at compile time.  This is so because generics are implemented in Java by *erasure*.  Most of the generic type information exists only at compile time and is erased at run time.

For this reason, **it is not possible to obtain a `Class` object for any non-reifiable type.**  The type information is not available at run time.

Not only can you not get a `Class` object for `Stream<String>`, but you can't get a `Class` object for any of `T`, `List<T>`, or `List<String>`.  These are all non-reifiable types.

The instanceof operator will only work with types from which a `Class` object can be obtained.  This is a good thing too, because `List<T>`, `List<String>`, and `List<Integer>` all share the same Class object at run time.  It would be confusing and error prone if the following snippet evaluated to `true`:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
boolean b = strings instanceof List<Integer>;
System.out.println(b);
```

Instead, the Java compiler does not allow the use of the `instanceof` operator on non-reifiable types.

Comment: You forgot to say that we can put `String` object into a `List<Integer>` :-)

Comment: An example I use for explaining is that the following assertion holds: `assert new ArrayList<Boolean>().getClass().equals(new ArrayList<String>().getClass())`

Answer (score 0):

To add to @scottb's answer, if you really needed this structure then you would need separate methods. You cannot overload the methods either due to erasure, so you have to name each method such that the method signatures are unique:

```
public boolean stringIsNullOREmpty(Stream<String> str) {
    //do some actions
}    

public boolean someClassIsNullOREmpty(Stream<SomeClass> str) {
    //do some actions
}
```